# Does photogrammetry have non-rigid 3D reconstruction methods?

Tags: computer-vision

## Prerequisites

I've found out that photogrammetry methods allow us to fetch 3D model from set of images of a scene. I call this *rigid reconstruction*.

There are methods of finding correspondence between two 3D scans even though scanned object performed non-rigid transformations between scans like [Global Correspondence Optimization for Non-Rigid Registration of Depth Scans](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.169.5590&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

## Question

Are there methods for 3D reconstruction by multiple photos, which take into account the fact that object may not only change its translation or rotation, but may also deform? If yes, how are they called and where should I start reading?

E. g., given a video (or videos) of speaking human, take a model of his/her face surface (without generative models and predefined templates); or reconstruct a model of t-shirt, which falls down on the floor and deforms, by series of images.

Comment: What does "3D reconstruction multiple photos" mean?  What are the inputs, and what is the desired output?  Are you given multiple 2D photos of a scene, and you are trying to reconstruct a 3D model of the scene?  Are the photos taken at the same time or at different times?  Are the photos taken from the same location or from multiple locations?  Is it a bunch of photos or is a video taken from a moving video camera?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://www.pervasive.jku.at/download/1988_Constraints%20on%20Deformable%20Models.pdf)? Based on the provided link, if you treat the reconstructed graph as the "spine" and the "confidence interval" it may look like reverse skinning method and possibly inverse kinematic chain, but this is only my idea, no clue if sufficient data could be read from movie. The t-shirt itself could be constructed using dense springs, but it will look jaggy. I personaly doubt that full tensor could be reconstructed even from long sequence so only visible deformations are valid.

Comment: @D.W. thanks for note, I've missed a word __by__

Comment: @Evil thanks, yes, the article touches the topic. As I understood, rigid 3D reconstruction is done first from binocular pair, and only then it tries to find non-rigid transform to fit the next binocular pair and so on (or from one image, not from pair). Makes sense. If I got your idea, you mean that without a priori knowledge about nature of motion of scanned object (bones system, springs set etc.) we cannot deal with non-rigid transformation, right?

Comment: @D.W. I want to know, whether methods for fetching 3D model of a non-rigidly deforming scene given a 2D input exist. If objects of the scene deform, it's obvious that at least one photo should be made not at the same time with another ones. I'm looking for an article, which covers this topic: which deformations can be reconstructed, how many photos of similar deformation should I take etc. In other words, what photos of an object, which changes non-rigidly, I should take in order to have an ability to reconstruct it, and is it possible to do this by photos made in different time.

Comment: @Evil could you, please, post an answer in order for me to mark it as the best one? It would be awesome to have domain-specific termonology related to the question, because I'm not familiar with photogrammetry and I don't know how things are called here.